# Feature Normalization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, matrix, matrix-multiplication

```
X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
for i = 1:2
    mu(1,i) = mean(X,(:,i));
    sigma(1,i) = std(X,0,(:,i));
    col_mu = ones(size(X,1), 1) * mu(:,i)
    X_norm(:,i) = X(:,i) - col_mu
    X_norm(:,i) = X(:,i) * (1/sigma(1,i))
end
end
```

I am trying to implement feature normalization as part of the Stanford Coursera ML Course. When I run this, I get an error message "invalid use of operator" for line 13, column 23.

The one that says (mu(1,i) = mean...

I was trying to make the i-th column of mu the mean of the i-th column of X. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a comma between X and (:, i).

Comment: `mean(X,(:,i));` and `std(X,0,(:,i));` is wrong syntax. You probably want `mean(X(:,i));` and `std(X(:,i), 0);`. This is Matlab. You should avoid loops and use matrix algebra.

Comment: How do I avoid doing loops if each individual column of X has to become normalized using only its own values and not those of other columns

Answer (score 1):

`mean(X,(:,i));` and `std(X,0,(:,i));` is wrong syntax. You probably want `mean(X(:,i));` and `std(X(:,i), 0);`. This is Matlab. You should avoid loops and use matrix algebra:

```
X_norm = X;
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X, 0);
col_mu = ones(size(X,1), 1) .* mu;
% X_norm = X - col_mu;
X_norm = X .* (1./sigma)
```

I removed `X_norm(:,i) = X(:,i) - col_mu` because it's overwritten in the direct next line.

Comment: Thanks for help. I know it is Matlab. I can read. I didn't realize that using mu = mean(X) would automatically take the mean of X's columns... why not rows?

Comment: @dgoodie Do you use the IDE? Do you see the warnings and the documentation in your IDE?

Comment: I'm using Matlab Online

Comment: Matlab is the programming language with the best documentation I know of: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html?searchHighlight=mean&s_tid=srchtitle _"If A is a matrix, then mean(A) returns a row vector containing the mean of each column."_

Comment: Thank you Thomas you are very helpful. A shining bastion in the sea of egotism that is this website.

Comment: @dgoodie This website has some strict rules to keep the high quality, e.g. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ Asking a question without reading the documentation is frowned upon by many users. That makes this platform less beginner friendly but it's the best platform I know of if you invest some effort into your question.